# codeigniter -> having trouble loading multiple libraries/classes

Tags: php, class, codeigniter

Ok, so in my base controller (page.php) I have the following code which works fine:

```
   $this->load->library('Siteclass');
   $mysite = new site_model();
```

The siteclass library references a model named site_model and instantiates based on data received from that model. All is good.

Now I want to load another library so that I can instantiate another object as well. So I add this to page.php:

```
 $this->load->library('Memberclass');
 $mysite = new member_model();
```

But now I get the following error:

```
 Message: Undefined property: Memberclass::$site_model
 Filename: libraries/Loader.php
 Line Number: 1035
```

From what I can tell, it seems that the loader class, when being applied to the Memberclass, is somehow still referencing the site_model instead of the member_model. I've checked my code and I am definitely calling the correct files.

Here's what Siteclass.php looks like:

```
 if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

 class Siteclass extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->model('Site_model');
        $data = $this->Site_model->load_site_data();
        // etc etc
```

and here's what Memberclass.php looks like:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Memberclass extends Controller {
function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
    $this->load->model('Member_model');
        $data = $this->Member_model->load_member_data();
        // etc etc
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gary

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confused about how MVC works in CodeIgniter. Why are you using the loader class to create a controller? Why are you creating a stand-alone instance of your model outside of your controller class?

In CodeIgniter, your URLs represent paths to your controllers' methods. That means that your "base controller" should automatically be instantiated if you go to:

> www.example.com/memberclass

Or perhaps more to the point, if you have a link like this:

> www.example.com/page

You should have a file in your `/application/controllers` directory called `page.php` which looks like this:

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Page extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
        // etc etc
```

Furthermore, unless you're loading data from your model to be used *every single time you call this controller*, you'll want to put your model calls inside a non-constructor method of this class. Something like:

```
class Page extends Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->model('Member_model');
        $data = $this->Member_model->load_member_data();
        $this->load->view('myview', array('data'=>$data));
    }
}
```

So again...not entirely sure what context you're doing this all in, but it seems like you're not standing firmly within the framework. There's basically no reason you should be using the loader class to load controllers, and furthermore there's no reason you should be creating stand-alone instances of model classes using PHP's `new` keyword.

Comment: @treeface - I don't think I meant to use the loader class to set up a controller. I meant to use the loader class to set up specific objects. When I originally set up the library I wasn't able to load the model. It seemed like model-loading only worked in the library when I made it a controller. Here's what I want to do:  my base controller is page.php and I am using __remap() so that all urls of /page/something go to this controller. From here, I want to be able to instantiate various objects based on defined classes like member, user, etc. Can you suggest the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: @treeface - ok, I think I am getting closer. In page.php I call the model, which returns back the data I need, *then* I call the library wherein I instantiate the object, by including that model data as part of the library call. Am I on the right path?

Comment: @Gary If you want to get data from a model inside your library, you need to get a reference to the CI controller that's currently being used. To do this in your controller, you should do this: `$CI =& get_instance();`. Now you can call the model by doing `$CI->my_model->getMyData();`.

Comment: @Gary and again, you should really be relying on CodeIgniter's [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) to do what you're trying to do. There's really no good reason why you should be sending every request on your site to `page.php`. That's effectively what CI does with the core routing. Instead, think about how you can break your site down into areas like main, photos, videos, forums, etc. You should give the CI user_guide a thorough read-through, specifically the section on [controllers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html).

Comment: @treeface - I do understand that, but I am developing a cms, and most (if not all) of the content will be dynamic. I want the end user to call a standardized url, and from there I'd have logic about what elements get put onto the page, so I want to route all calls through /page/whatever. It seems to me that most CMSs work that way.

Comment: @Gary Take a look at the code behind [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/), a CMS built on CodeIgniter. Phil Sturgeon (a big contributor on CodeIgniter) created it using CodeIgniter, so if I were you, I'd take a look at what he does in this regard. Reading through the source code might give you a lot of good guidance (and other ideas) on what you should do with your CMS.